# How to measure continuity between two FPGAs

Tags: fpga, continuity

I have two FPGAs, one will contain test chip and one contain memory and I2S interface and some control signals for jtag. Right now the chip is not available on the board but its connections are such as balls are exposed. Can I check continuity of those signals that are connected  between these two FPGAs without damaging the balls. 
The problem is I don't have test points for all the signals, thats why I wanted to do a bring up test.

Answer (score 2):

Chips have balls, PCBs don't. You can safely use your ohmmeter probes on the pads of your board without damaging anything.

Comment: Yeah I mean the balls of the chip will connect on the connections provided. The connections are very close and what if I touch one ground connection to a not ground pin while using ohmmeter or voltameter?

Comment: Get pointier probes! The ohmmeter by itself won't damage anything anyway.  But if you apply power and try to measure voltages, a slipped probe could allow the power supply to blow a narrow track. Just turn the current limit on the supply  all the way down,  or use a separate series resistor to limit the current to a safe level.